# Accessing Slide object in PowerPoint add-in

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I'm building a add-in for PowerPoint and need to access the Slides or Slide objects, or even the whole presentation; alas, the only method I can see of doing this is to open a *new* ppt file. Right now I'm having to resort to the hacky method of saving the current presentation and reopening it with Packaging to manipulate anything (more specifically I'm having to SHA the Slide objects from the pptx file to see if they've changed -- not ideal)

Is there any way to open the file that is currently open in PowerPoint w/o having to IO a file?

Thanks for your help,
P

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created a PowerPoint (2007/2010) Add-In Project in VisualStudio. In general you can Access the active presentation with static class `Globals` this way:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[slideIndex] ...
```

Edit: Example for usage:

```
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

...

try
{
    int numberOfSlides = Globals.ThisAddIn
        .Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count;

    if (numberOfSlides > 0)
    {
        // get first slide
        PowerPoint.Slide firstSlide = Globals.ThisAddIn
            .Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[0];

        // get first shape (object) in the slide
        int shapeCount = firstSlide.Shapes.Count;

        if (shapeCount > 0)
        {
            PowerPoint.Shape firstShape = firstSlide.Shapes[0];
        }

        // add a label
        PowerPoint.Shape label = firstSlide.Shapes.AddLabel(
                Orientation: Microsoft.Office.Core
                   .MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
                Left: 100,
                Top: 100,
                Width: 200,
                Height: 100);

        // write hello world with a slidenumber
        label.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello World! Page: ";
        label.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertSlideNumber();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @JanW. Do you know if you can safely serialize/deserialize this object to access its contents?

Comment: Added an example. Dont think about serialization/dirty workarrounds. The ObjectModel of Office Interop is almost complete. You can access everything through managed objects like in the edited post.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for the late reply. What I'm seeking to do now is copy slides between presentations. The only way I've been able to do this thus far is to use InsertFromFile() as I cannot access the slide object directly on the ActivePresentation. I'm seeking to get pretty low-level with the manipulation, so do you know if there is a method to access the object in memory (as opposed to doing file I/O any time I want to copy slides from one presentation to another!). Thanks again -- really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean copying slides between two opened instances of powerpoint? Or do you want to chose the file in a Dialog or something to copy the slides from?