# How to format textbox in powerpoint slide

Tags: c#, powerpoint

How can I format textbox? Because now it is using the last format (no bold and size 20), but I need to have a Title with different format (bold and size 30). I found that I can do this with richtextbox, but I don´t know how to add richtextbox to the slides.

```
PowerPoint.Shape textBox = activeSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox( Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50, 50, 600, 500);
textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 30;
textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("This is Title with font size 30 and bold.");
textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20;
textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("This is normal text with font size 20 and no bold.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link. It shows you how.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159403(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159403%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**
So you asked how to add a richtextbox:

```
Dim rtfBox As RichTextBox = New RichTextBox
rtfBox.Paste()
```

Then you can edit rtfBox to the format that you wish. Simple as that. Or you can make a template and use the [Apply Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._slide.applytemplate%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Method.

Here are some other links that might help you. They mention editing the slides and changing the font:

[PowerPoint C# Examples](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/create-powerpoint-ppt-programmatically-using-c/)

[Accessing Slide StackFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688188/accessing-slide-object-in-powerpoint-add-in)

[SunFine Data](http://www.sunfinedata.com/programming/c/create-powerpoint-slide-in-c/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Could you be more precise? Because I don't see anything useful.

Comment: This should go under comments!! This not answer the question directly

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you'd do it in VBA. You can use the length of the different text strings and .Characters to return a text range that you format however you like w/o affecting the other text.

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim sBoldText As String
Dim sNotBoldText As String

sBoldText = "This is the title, 30 and bold."
sNotBoldText = " This is the other text, 20 and not bold."

Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 500, 100)
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sBoldText & sNotBoldText

With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1, Len(sBoldText))
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 30
End With
With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Len(sBoldText) + 1)
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 20
End With
```